# Force autocomplete to top of navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, autocomplete, livesearch

I am trying to use jQuery-UI autocomplete live search in my project nav-bar, but when live search appears, it hides behind my nav-bar. I've use z-index but it not longer works. What should I do?

Here's the picture:

[image: livesearch behind navbar]

here's my code :

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-8">
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-center" role="search" method="get">
    <div class="input-group searchbar">
        <input id="cari" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Aku mau belanja.." name="q">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button id="sb" class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

when I inspect the live search, it becomes:
[image]

so I give style :

```
<style type="text/css">
  .ui-menu .ui-menu-item-wrapper {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 100000;
 }
 .container-fluid {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 30;
 }
</style>
```

but it does not work either. What should I do?

**EDIT:**

```css
   .ui-menu .ui-menu-item-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100000;
    }
    .container-fluid {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 30;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>ShoppingKuy</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"
  integrity="sha256-0YPKAwZP7Mp3ALMRVB2i8GXeEndvCq3eSl/WsAl1Ryk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
   <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-8">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-center" role="search" method="get">
        <div class="input-group searchbar">
            <input id="cari" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="I want to buy" name="q">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button id="sb" class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cari").autocomplete({
      source: "<?php echo base_url();?>core/liveSearch",
      autoFocus : false,
      minLength : 2
    });

  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create a snippet of complete working code

Comment: I use codeigniter framework. I hope you'll uderstand my snippet hehe